# How to minimize the minimum of a set of convex functions?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima, numerical-optimization

I know that the minimum of a set of convex functions is not necessarily convex. However, are there quick numerical techniques that can be used to find the minimum of a set of convex functions?

In other words, let

$$f(x) = \min_x\{g_1(x), g_2(x), ... g_n(x)\}.$$

If $g_i$ are all convex, then what is a good strategy for minimizing $f$?

EDIT: several people have brought up the fact that the answer depends on the details about $n$ and the computational cost of computing the minima for each $g$. Some more details that might help:

- $n$ is very large, generally $100!$ to $1000!$. These are functions in $R^{100} \to R$, or in other words $x \in R^{100}$, but each $g_i$ can be minimized quite quickly.
- The connection between each function is that each $g_i$ is defined as the distance between a particular permutation of the entries of a vector $y \in R^{100}$ and $x$.

Comment: It's hard to say much without information about the cost of evaluation for the $g_i$'s and any difficulties related to their domains.

Comment: If you need the global minimum then, perhaps, you need to compute the minimum of all $g_i$'s.

Comment: Exactly, @MathLover. Indeed I'm not seeing the difficulty here. One simply must minimize them all. Of course, it's possible that some efficiencies can be gained by carefully monitoring each subproblem separately and stopping one early if it can be proven that it cannot beat the current best.

Comment: Maybe you could minimize the lower convex envelope of the $g_i$, the pointwise maximum of all convex or affine functions whose graphs lie below those of the $g_i$.  There might exist some combination of circumstances where this is the efficient way to proceed.

Comment: These are good points -- let me edit the question with more details

Comment: I don't get it, what means "the distance between a particular permutation of the entries of a vector $y\in\mathbb{R}^{100}$ and x". Could explain that more specifically?

Answer (score 3):

If the number of your convex functions is finite, it's available to find their minimum **respectively** and compare them together to find the "**minimum minimum**". Because a convex function has only one or doesn't have a **minimum value**.

If one of the convex functions doesn't have a minimum value, then your $f(x)$ doesn't have one too.

I don't know if it's the best way but **maybe it is in all probability** because we don't know the connection between these functions. The minimum of $f(x)$ indeed lies in one of the minimums among $g(x)$'s. If you don't know their connection, there's no way you find which one is the smallest unless you check them all.